# Is $T$ nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra

let $T$ be the linear transformation from the real vector  space  $\mathbb{R}[x] $ to itself  given $T(f) = f'$ where $f'$ is the derivative  of $f$ .

Now choose the correct option

$1.$ $T$ is nilpotent

$2.$The only eigenvalue of $T$ is $0$

$3.$ $T$ is  not nilpotent

$4.$The only eigenvalue of $T$ is not $0$

My attempt : If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ then  $$T(f)=\lambda f \implies f'=\lambda f \implies (\log f)' =\lambda \implies  f= e^{\lambda x }.e^c $$

Now $f(0)= e^c \tag 1$

But here $T$ is a linear transformation so $T(0)=0 \implies Tf(0)=0 \implies f(0)=0 \tag2$

From $(1)$  and $(2)  $ $\implies  f(0)=e^c$  . Contradiction

Therefore  $Tf$ has  no eigenvalue

so option $(3)$ and $(4)$ are correct

Am  i right ?

Comment: $f'=\lambda f$ is not limited to $f=ce^{\lambda x}$ with $c>0$, all $c<0$ are also solutions, and $c=0$ giving $f=0$ is also solution. So overall you get all $c\in\mathbb R$. The mistake you make is that $f'/f$ integrates to $\ln|f|$ (this is how you get negative $c$), the case $f=0$ comes as a side solution (before you are allowed to write $f'/f$).

Comment: $T(0)=0$ does not imply $Tf(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a bit confused:

**Option (1)**

This is false.No matter how many times you compose $T$ with itself. If you compose it $n$ times, it won't be $0$ on polynomials of degree higher than $n-1$.

**Option (2)**

This is true. As you noticed, the only way for $f(x)$ to be an eigenvector is to be a constant polynomial and clearly the derivative of a constant is $0$, so the only eigenvalue is $0$.

**Option (3)**

This is true because option 1 is false.

**Option (4)**

This is false because option 2 is true.

Comment: $0$ is never an eigenvector.

Comment: Sorry, I meant eigenvalue. Now I corrected.

Comment: $T$ *is* "locally nilpotent", though: for every $f$, there exists $n$ such that $T^n f = 0$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler and this is a big hammer to prove that $\mathbb{R}[X]$ is not complete, since in a complete space, locally nilpotent implies nilpotent ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missed on $T(0)=0 \implies T(f(0))=0$

Option (1)
We know the dimension of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is infinite.
So, no matter how many times you compose T
with itself, it won't be 0
So option (1) is false

Option (2)

This is true. As if $ \lambda \neq0$ we have $f=e^{\lambda x}e^c$ which is not in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. So the only possibility is $ \lambda =0$. Also for the constant function derivative is $0$. So $0$ is the eigenvalue for the constant function.
So the only eigenvalue is $0$. In your answer you $T(0)=0$ does not implies $T(f(0))=0$. Here $f(0)$ is not a function.

Option (3)

This is true because option 1 is false.

Option (4)

This is false because option 2 is true.